# iterator_to_array freezes, e.g. gets Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded

Tags: php, kint

i get

> Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in
>   ../src/kint/parsers/custom/objectiterateable.php on line 10

the problematic line does this:

```
$arrayCopy = iterator_to_array( $variable, true );
```

some lines around it:

```
if ( !KINT_PHP53 || !is_object( $variable ) || !$variable instanceof Traversable ) return false;


    $arrayCopy = iterator_to_array( $variable, true );

    if ( $arrayCopy === false ) return false;

    $this->value = kintParser::factory( $arrayCopy )->extendedValue;
    $this->type  = 'Iterator contents';
    $this->size  = count( $arrayCopy );
```

is there something to make the iterator_to_array more secure? e.g. just return nothing in some cases?

Answer (score 0):

use `set_time_limit(0)` in your page

Comment: i don't want to totally deadlock my computer... this must be a dead loop. Setting it to 0 pretty much means having to restart apache again.